Shapes.Item(i) cannot change the text
Here is my code. The debug only show Rectangle items.
Public Sub Extract_Text()
    Dim shps As Shapes
    Dim q As Integer
    
    Set shps = ActivePage.Shapes
   
    For q = 1 To shps.Count
      shps.Item(q).Characters = "test" & LTrim(shps.Item(q).Characters)
      Debug.Print shps.Item(q)
    Next q

    Debug.Print "OK"
End Sub

I want to change each text in the rectangle.
but it didn't work.
Here is rectangles I writed

At my side your code works! Please try change .Characters to .Text.
